# Calling another process from python/child process need to access shell

Tags: c++, python, c, unix, subprocess

I'm calling a C/C++ program from python with `Popen`, python code should observe behavior of child process and collect some data for his own work.

Problem is that C code already uses pipes for calling some shell commands - so after my execution from python, C program cannot execute bash shell command.

Is there any way in calling from `Popen` to specify that, child process should execute his own pipe command in shell???

I tried with shell=True, but doesn't help!

Comment: What do you mean by "observe"? If the child process is using its stdout to talk with another subprocess, it can't use it to talk to the parent. Perhaps it uses stderr. Please provide more information.

Comment: Ok,
child (c code) is developed, and already uses stdout to talk with superprocess (shell). Now python should just call child, collect something that he writes on stderr, but child still needs to be able to talk with now super-superprocess (shell) in order to execute some shell commands!

Comment: I have only a vague idea what you are trying to do.  I suspect that when you say that the C program is sending its stdout to the shell what you actually mean is that it is printed to the screen.  I also suspect that you are fighting the fact that lots of APIs that deal with pipes don't allow you to pipe in and out of the same program at the same time (popen).  I don't know what the Python API looks like for this, but there are reasons for this, and there are ways to get around it in C by using lower level functions.  Try typing "man pipe" on your command line

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it seems that you are using Popen to execute a command line, which has Popen call a shell.

You should instead have Popen call your program directly, like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
p = Popen(['/my/fancy/program','-myarg1','-myarg2'],stdout=PIPE)
from_process = p.communicate()[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to use a TCP connection to localhost. If you are using a *nix, you can probably do it by opening a temporary file and polling it from the host application.